# Editing dynamic text in ArcGIS Pro to get 100k Grid zone labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, dynamic-text, mgrs

While making maps with MGRS I need to have a label in each corner of the map frame with the 100k grid square labels.

So far i have updated them manually, but after i've started using ArcGIS Pro i found that it is possible to extract Mapframe coordinates like "Upper left".

The syntax looks like this:
`<dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="upperLeft" units="dms" decimalPlaces="0"/>`

By pure curiosity i replaced "dms" with "mgrs", and it gave me a MGRS Grid without decimals.

```
<dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="upperLeft" units="mgrs" decimalPlaces="0"/>
```

Resulting in: 32VMH

Basically i would like to know to know if it is possible to remove the Grid zone designator "32V" so i end up only having "MH" left.

Comment: In ArcMap, this requires adding/populating a field, as dynamic text can't really use Python/VB expressions. A klugy solution: add a white filled graphic box over the first part of the label.